# How to access 'Settings' property of ElasticClient in NEST?

Tags: nest

I've recently updated my NEST dll to the latest version and now I cannot access the settings e.g.

```
client.Settings.Host
```

I used this to log the ES host I was currently connected to.

Comment: Which version is latest ?

Comment: According to the Version in the Properties panel, it's 0.12.0.0